# Want to edit just one word in car file how to edit it in wso2

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator

I have made a car file and just want to change one word in one of the multiple sequences. Any way I can edit it save it and redeploy it without making an entire project for that car file.

Any leads would mean a lot.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows.

1. Rename the .car file to a zip.
2. Unzip the file
3. Change relevant files.
4. Zip the artifacts.
5. Rename to car extension.

Comment: Can you please guide how to rename to car extension? Simple .zip to .car ?

Answer (score 0):

Car files are `.zip` archives. If you are on linux, the easiest way to do it is to use a tool like `vim`. First, change the extension of the car file to `.zip` and then use vim to update the files interactively, then change the extension back. Example commands below.

```
mv carFileName.car carFileName.zip
vim carFileName.zip
mv carFileName.zip carFileName.car
```

Answer (score 0):

I do frequently such minor changes in car files.
For that, I use mc (Midnight Commander) available on both Linux and MacOS.
You can just browse inside the car file, edit the needed file directly and then save it.
I think it's the easiest way.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).